# How to use StickySwitch library by Mr.GwonHyeok as simple On?Off toggle button?

Tags: android

i want to implement simple on/off toggle button to display notification channel and to stop the notification channel from the activity itself, using stickySwitch by gwonHyeok.

my code is below,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);
        mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(mChannel.getLockscreenVisibility());

        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    stickySwitch = findViewById(R.id.sticky_switch);
    stickySwitch.setOnSelectedChangeListener(new StickySwitch.OnSelectedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedChange(StickySwitch.Direction direction, String s) {
            if(stickySwitch.s) ???????????????????? Help????
        }
    });
}

public void displayNotification() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_panda)
            .setContentTitle("Panda")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

and my xml ........................................

```
<io.ghyeok.stickyswitch.widget.StickySwitch
    android:id="@+id/sticky_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:ss_animationDuration="500"
    app:ss_iconPadding="18dp"
    app:ss_iconSize="22dp"
    app:ss_leftIcon="@drawable/ic_pandaOff"
    app:ss_leftText="OFF"
    app:ss_rightIcon="@drawable/ic_pandaOn"
    app:ss_rightText="ON"
    app:ss_selectedTextSize="14sp"
    app:ss_sliderBackgroundColor="@color/colorSliderBackground"
    app:ss_switchColor="@color/colorSwitchColor"
    app:ss_textColor="@color/colorTextColor"
    app:ss_textSize="12sp"
    app:ss_animationType="curved"
    app:ss_textVisibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you wan`t?

Comment: why don't you ask Mr.GwonHyeok this question?

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi: a toggle button to on/off the notification using stickyswitch instead of default toggle button provided by android.

Comment: @RaviKilnake Okay. Then where you stuck.

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi: onSelectchangeListener. please see the code.

Comment: Can you post your xml file?

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi : see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set condition in `setOnSelectedChangeListener` ,

```
    StickySwitch stickySwitch = findViewById(R.id.sticky_switch);
        stickySwitch.setOnSelectedChangeListener(new StickySwitch.OnSelectedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedChange(StickySwitch.Direction direction, String s) {
                if (direction == StickySwitch.Direction.LEFT) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click on Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click on Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.cancelAll();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: how to stop the notification  inside 'else' statement?